# Excel move phone number from row

Tags: excel

I have an Excel list with phone numbers but some of the rows have 2 phone numbers in it, I need to move the second number right under or at least to move them all to a new column. How can I achieve that ?

[image: img]

Comment: You could use `FIND` to find a space and then `RIGHT`/`LEFT`/`MID` to get only the text to the left or right of the space.

Comment: I would start by deciding what you want to do; move under in the same cell, move under in new cell or move right in new cell.

Comment: See [**Split text into different columns with the Convert Text to Columns Wizard**](https://support.office.com/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7).